# Set the T template type at runtime passing a variable

Tags: java, templates

Is there way to pass a `Class` variable when instanciating a new template class named `TemplateClass` or is it absolutely a non-sens ?

Example of something i would like to do but that do not compile:

```
final List<TemplateClass> fields = new ArrayList<>();

public void loadDataFields() {
    for(Field x : ClassA.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        fields.add(new TemplateClass<x.getClass()>());
    }
}
```

#### Edit

Here is the `TemplateClass` :

```
public class TemplateClass<T extends Comparable> {
    int count;
    T min;
    T max; 
}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps show your `TemplateClass` class and how it uses the `T` type parameter? It may help someone to suggest a workable solution.

Comment: As the answers mention it, you cannot use a `Class` value expression as concrete type parameter. Because your fields can have different data types, maybe the best is to declare `fields` as `List<TemplateClass<Comparable>>` and cast values to `Comparable` where applicable (can't avoid the raw type) - (to avoid class cast exceptions, maybe you should check `if(Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(x.getType()))`). The rest depends on how your `TemplateClass` is using the `min` and `max` fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - No.

There is no way it instantiates a template with dynamic class in runtime. That is because templates are evaluated at build time.

Answer (score 3):

In Java generics are evaluated as (mostly) compile time information due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Line `new TemplateClass<x.getClass()>()` makes no sense as `x.getClass()` is only evaluated in runtime. This line would result in compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

You can not assign a `Type` as a generic class at run time.

Generics can be used **only** at compile time.